# Is DataContext incompatible with ContextMenu?

Tags: wpf, xaml

In this post

http://paulstovell.com/blog/six-years-of-wpf

the author suggests that "Data context is a great concept, except it totally breaks when dealing with items like ContextMenus."

Is this true?  Are there some specific examples to back this up?

Comment: Maybe you can find an answer to your question [here][1]?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033522/wpf-contextmenu-woes-how-do-i-set-the-datacontext-of-the-contextmenu

Comment: this article seems to document the problem well   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/162784/WPF-ContextMenu-Strikes-Again-DataContext-Not-Upda  describing in detail the 'magic spell' that needs to be used when the ContextMenu, not being part of the 'visual tree' loses track of it's DataContext.