# ContextMenu commands on DataGrid Row do not work

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, row

I create a style than I bind it to a `DataGrid.RowStyle` `Row` style. The `ContextMenu` appears and I am able to select from the menu items, but the **command** won't execute. I tested the **command** with other control and works fine.

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridRow"  TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
     <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
         <Setter.Value>
              <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                    <MenuItem Header="Add" Command="{Binding AddMessageContextMenu_Command}"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Edit" Command="{Binding EditMessage_Command}"/>
              </ContextMenu>
           </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
<Style>

<DataGrid Name="SearchTableDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchTableDataGrid_ItemSource}"
   <DataGrid.RowStyle>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
          <Style.Triggers>
             <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                   <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FBFCFC" />
              </Trigger>
              <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                   <Setter Property="Background" Value="#f6f8f8" />
              </Trigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Related link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033522/wpf-contextmenu-woes-how-do-i-set-the-datacontext-of-the-contextmenu

Comment: I used tag but command still doesn't execute.

Comment: You need to examine your bindings at runtime using the tools in visual studio 2015 or something like Snoop.

Answer (score 1):

You need a reference to the right DataContext. As suggested in the comments, you can use the Rows `Tag` property for this.

Below the code to get to the Windows DataContext

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="Tag" 
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, 
                            Path=DataContext}"/>
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, 
                                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                <MenuItem Header="Add" Command="{Binding AddMessageContextMenu_Command}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Edit" Command="{Binding EditMessage_Command}"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks, I declared a different **RelativeSource**. Now it binds to the correct command.