# Cannot use DataContext of parent from within styles

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I got some problems accessing a specific DataContext from within a Style.
I have a `DataGrid` defined like this:

```
<DataGrid Name="ReferenceDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="???" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    ...
```

The `DataContext` property of the `Page` containing this `DataGrid` is set to

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

I want to bind a `RelayCommand` to the `MenuItem` and tried several different ways to do this:

- `Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"`
- `Command="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DeleteCommand}"` // Page element's name set to Root
- `Command="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand}"`
- `Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"`

I set a breakpoint in the command handler of `DeleteCommand` but none of the variations above got there.

Let's say `Items` contains elements of type `Foo`.
If I define the command in `Foo` the handler gets triggered so it seems that whatever I've done above, the `DataContext` of each `DataGridRow` seems to be the list element itself.

Any idea what to do about it?

**Edit:**
I also tried to extract the `DataContext` into a separate class and reference this instead of `Relative Self` as I thought the list elements might use `Relative Self` as their `DataContext` instead of the `Page` instance it refers to. Unfortunately I was wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF ContextMenu woes: How do I set the DataContext of the ContextMenu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033522/wpf-contextmenu-woes-how-do-i-set-the-datacontext-of-the-contextmenu)

Comment: Nope, doesn't work either. Maybe I have to do something different because I use Styles and not DataTemplates?

Comment: Will you only ever be using commands which are in the same datacontext as the DataGrid?

Comment: @Andy So far I always only had one DataContext per Page/Window etc. I really don't want to clutter up the model classes with this stuff so I store them in the Page's DataContext. I also need to update several other properties in the DataContext so extracting parts of it into separate ones wouldn't give any benefit

Comment: Actually... that's a good thing. I'll post a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are only interested in commands in one place, there's another way to do this you might find useful.
Define the contextmenu as a resource where it can grab that datacontext, then apply that to the datagrid rows.
I've done this on a sample which was originally intended for another purpose so my objects and stuff are different.

```
<DataGrid 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" 
    Background="White" 
    Name="dg"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}"
          >
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="dgContextMenu"
                     DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}">
            <MenuItem Header="Up" Command="{Binding UpCommand}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource dgContextMenu}"/>
```

DataContext inherits down the visual tree, so the datagrid gets the same datacontext as a page or window or whatever it's in.
My contextmenu is  actually in the datagrid and can get it's datacontext.

I also bind selecteditem so I can use that to work out which specific row was clicked.

In the viewmodel for the window I have a command "UpCommand" that uses properties of the selected user.

```
    public RelayCommand UpCommand { get; set; }
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
          UpCommand = new RelayCommand(UpExecute);
    }
    public User SelectedUser { get; set; }
    private void UpExecute()
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"You Upped {SelectedUser.Title}");
    }
```

You could remove the selected user from Users and or use it's ID to delete the record off a database or whatever delete is to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ContextMenu  DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <MenuItem Header="Delete"  Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand}" />
</ContextMenu>
```

As you could see in answer to the duplicate question, that the problem is:

> The ContextMenu is outside of the visual tree

If you don't want to put the `DeleteCommand` to the object, which is an entry in `Items`, than you can set`Source` propery for `Binding` with `x:Reference`.

```
<DataGrid Name="ReferenceDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu  DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, Source={x:Reference ReferenceDataGrid}}">
                        <MenuItem Header="Delete"  Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: I already tried this solution but it doesn't work like I said in the comments.

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure you have a GridRowDataContextDeleteCmd in object which is DataContext for the DataGridRow?

Comment: Please, see that `DataContext` of `ContextMenu` is set.

Comment: I am trying to reproduce the issue and it is showing error 4. I have also tried your solution with `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` to no avail. I think an event handler might be the solution here.

Comment: @Rekshino I copy pasted your code to assure there are no typos on my side but it still doesn't work. The command instance exists. I created a button next to the DataGrid and let it trigger this command with success, so I assume that the command instance itself is not the problem.

Comment: `DeleteCommand` must be in object, which is DataContext for DataGridRow(!!!), not in main ViewModel

Comment: Try `Header="{Binding DataContext}"` to see what you are dealing with

Comment: `DataContext` for `MenuItem` is `DataGridRow`.

Comment: It rather depends on what delete is going to do of course. Usually it's going to involve removing a row. That is often much more practical if the command is in the viewmodel which has the collection you bind to the itemssource of a datagrid.

Comment: @Andy Either way I have posted solutions for both cases. I would expect that question has mCve and here I can only guess where is the command.