# How to have custom SubMenus in a MenuItem where an ItemSource and ItemContainer are being used?

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, itemsource, itemcontainerstyle

I am writing a C# application using WFP and the MVVM pattern.

In my view, I have a TreeView and each Item in that Tree View has its own Context Menu displayed when the user right clicks. The behavior I want a SubMenu within the Context Menu's Menu item that also allows for an Item Source to be supported.

Here is a text version of what I'd like:
ContextMenu   (items sourced from an Item Source)
MenuItem_A  (item sourced from an Item Source)
SubMenuItem_A
MenuItem_B  (might not have any sub-items)

Here's what I tried:

```html
<TreeView x:Name="MyTreeView" Tag={Binding ElementName=MyTreeView, Path=DataContext}>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate> 
        <HeriarachicalDataTemplate DataType={x:Type namespace:ItemsViewModel} 
            <Grid> 
                <Grid.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu 
    DataContext={Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSouce={Self}} ItemSource ={Binding HostedMenuOptions}>
                    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="MenuItem"> 
                            <Setter Property="Header" Value={Binding HostedMenuItemName}> 
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAcestor, AncestorType={x:TYpe ContextMenu}}, Path=DataContext.HostedMenuItemSubMenus}/>
                        </Style> 
                    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle> 
                </Grid.ContextMenu> 
            </Grid> 
        </HerarchicalDataTemplate> 
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

The error that I'm seeing is an xaml binding error:
HostedMenuItemName property not found on object of RunTimeType

Is there another way to achieve this?
Basically I want the contextmenu, menus and submenus to to be determined by lists of objects that are stored in the ViewModel.

Comment: Placementtarget is the thing you should google.  The context menu is in a separate window so doesn't inherit datacontext.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033522/wpf-contextmenu-woes-how-do-i-set-the-datacontext-of-the-contextmenu

Comment: An alternative is to define whatever you want in the contextmenu as a resource somewhere whose datacontext is say the window.

Comment: I do have the PlacementTag set so the ContextMenu is getting the correct data context of the treeview. 
I can update the question to reflect that

Comment: The menu items are coming from the ItemSource that are set in the context menu.

Comment: That menuitem itemssource binding will have the datacontext of your menuitem. Where's your tag and placementtarget binding?

Comment: The datacontext of a menuitem subitems you get in the contextmenu will not need any of that relativesource binding. Their itemssource should just be {Binding ChildCollection}

Comment: That cannot be your real markup though. You have no quotes around those bindings

Answer (score 0):

Here's some experimental markup I tried.

I have a treeview which is bound to a collection of family which itself has family members.

As a quick and dirty experiment I added a class MenuThing

```
public class MenuThing : baseVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<MenuThing> MenuChildren { get; set; }
}
```

In my treeview resources I define a contextmenu as a resource:

```
            <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuThings}" x:Key="ContextMenuAsResource">
                <ContextMenu.Resources>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MenuThing}" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuChildren}">
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </ContextMenu.Resources>
            </ContextMenu>
        </TreeView.Resources>
```

Note that this will just be looking for a collection called MenuThings in the viewmodel a treeviewitem is bound to.

And I have a hierarchicaldatatemplate for family:

```
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Family}" ItemsSource="{Binding Members}">
               <Border>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                Height="32"
                                ContextMenu="{DynamicResource ContextMenuAsResource}"
                                >
                        <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="WingDings" Content="1"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Note that this template references the contextmenu resource.

This gets round some of that placementtarget stuff.

My contextmenu doesn't have any commands of course but it does display.

[image]

If some of the treeviewitems won't have commands then you'll get a sort of empty little box. You'd probably want to suppress that. But maybe every one of your treeviewitems will have commands.

My data setup.

```
    Families = new ObservableCollection<Family>();

    Family family1 = new Family() { Name = "The Doe's" };

    family1.MenuThings = new List<MenuThing>
    {
        new MenuThing{ Name="AA", MenuChildren=new List<MenuThing>{new MenuThing{Name ="AAA" }, new MenuThing { Name = "AAB" } } },
        new MenuThing{ Name="BB", MenuChildren=new List<MenuThing>{new MenuThing{Name ="BBB" }, new MenuThing { Name = "BBBB" } } }
    };

    family1.Members.Add(new FamilyMember() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42 });
                    family1.Members.Add(new FamilyMember() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39 });
                    family1.Members.Add(new FamilyMember() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 13 });
                    Families.Add(family1);

                    Family family2 = new Family() { Name = "The Moe's" };
    family2.Members.Add(new FamilyMember() { Name = "Mark Moe", Age = 31 });
                    family2.Members.Add(new FamilyMember() { Name = "Norma Moe", Age = 28 });
                    Families.Add(family2);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, that empty little box and the strange display that is being show on your MenuItem AAA. Is becuase you have a menu item that is getting wrapped in a menu item. To get around that you can use an itemcontainerstyle. 

I'll give this a try with the heriarchical data template at the context menu level like you have shown

Comment: Think you could use a datatrigger to collapse the context menu if there are zero items if it's an issue.

Comment: Thanks Andy, the key was using a hierarchical data template. You were close with your proposed solution and it did lead me in the right direction. 

I'll update this post with what I ended up getting work.