# Can't bind to DelegateCommand of ViewModel from within DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am trying to put a ContextMenu into cells of one column of a DataGrid.
Clicking on a menu item of the ContextMenu should execute a command.

[image]

I can show the ContextMenu but the command is not executed and a binding error shows

> ICommand  TimePointOnCommand property not found on object of type
> Customer.

I dont want to have the ICommand     on the Customer object but on the ViewModel

Is there some way to execute the command TimePointOnCommand whenever the user selects a menu  item in the contect menu?

The project is as Prism project generated by the Prism template "Prism Full App"

This is my view

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="*" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"

                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

                                <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                    <ContextMenu>
                                        <MenuItem
                                            Header="An Zeitpunkt festlegen"
                                            Command="{  Binding Path=TimePointOnCommand}" />
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

This is the ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Regions;
using PrismWpf.Core.Mvvm;
using PrismWpf.Services.Interfaces;

namespace PrismWpf.Modules.ModuleName.ViewModels
{
    public class ViewAViewModel : RegionViewModelBase
    {

        public DelegateCommand TimePointOnCommand { get; private set; }

        private ObservableCollection<Customer> _customers;

   
        public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers
        {
            get => _customers;
            set => SetProperty(ref _customers, value);
        }

  
  
        public ViewAViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager, IMessageService messageService) :
            base(regionManager)
        {
            TimePointOnCommand = new DelegateCommand(SetOn);

            Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>
            {
                new() { Name = "John Doe", Id = 1, IsValid = true, Birthdate = new DateTime(2022, 4, 15, 10, 4, 2) },
                new() { Name = "Jane Smith", Id = 2, IsValid = false, Birthdate = new DateTime(2022, 6, 15, 8, 2, 2) }
            };
        }

        private void SetOn()
        {
        }

        public override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The issue only happens for a ContextMenu
For a button i can use

```
<Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},Mode=FindAncestor},Path=DataContext.TimePointOnCommand}" >Go</Button>
```

But I realy need a ContextMenu here

Comment: It's been a while since I've used wpf, but have you tried setting the datacontext to ViewAViewModel?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but close enough [WPF ContextMenu woes: How do I set the DataContext of the ContextMenu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033522/wpf-contextmenu-woes-how-do-i-set-the-datacontext-of-the-contextmenu) You want to move the command on the customer, probably

Comment: @Haukinger I tried the accepted answer of that post but for me PlacementTarget.Tag is not existing

Comment: @ShakHam How would I do that?

Comment: You can do it in the wpf itself:
<Window.DataContext>
        <local: ViewAViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

Or in the UI c# class:
public YourView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewAViewModel();
}

Comment: So just wondering, what if you do Binding TimePointOnCommand instead of Binding Path=TimePointOnCommand

Comment: you can use anything as a substitue for the `Tag`, I once defined a proxy in the resources that just holds the root data context: `{Binding Path=Data.SomeCommandForTheContextMenu, Source={StaticResource Proxy}}`

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case: the `ContextMenu` is not part of the same visual that the `TextBlock` belongs to. And the `TextBlock` or the `DataGridTemplateColumn` is not a child of the visual tree that the `DataGrid` belongs to. Inside the `ContextMenu` you are two disconnected visual trees away from your view model.

One option is to move the `TimePointOnCommand` command to the item model. The item model is the value of the `ContextMenu.DataContext` property.

An alternative solution is to move the `ContextMenu`.
Because your `ContextMenu` does not depend on the individual data items, you can safely move the `ConetxtMenu` to the `DataGrid`. From there you have easy access to the proper `DataContext`:

```xml
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(ContextMenuService.PlacementTarget).DataContext}">  
      <MenuItem Header="An Zeitpunkt festlegen"
                Command="{Binding TimePointOnCommand}" />
    </ContextMenu>
  </DataGrid.ContextMenu>

  <DataGrid.Columns>
    ...
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

### Update

To associate the `ContextMenu` with a particular column, you can define a `DataGrid.CellStyle` instead. Let the `Style` implement the appropriate triggers that identify the correct column to enable the `ContextMenu`.

The following example only shows a `ContextMenu` for the second column (`DataGridColumn.DisplayIndex` == `1`).
A `IValueConverter` is used to get the `DataGrid.DataContext` via visual tree traversal:

```xml
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <Setter Property="ContextMenuService.IsEnabled"
              Value="False" />
      <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(ContextMenuService.PlacementTarget), Converter={StaticResource DataGridCellToDataGridDataContextConverter}}">
            <MenuItem Header="An Zeitpunkt festlegen"
                      Command="{Binding TimePointOnCommand}" />
          </ContextMenu>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>

      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Column.DisplayIndex}"
                     Value="1">
          <Setter Property="ContextMenuService.IsEnabled"
                  Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.CellStyle>

  <DataGrid.Columns>
    ...
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

```cs
public class DataGridCellToDataGridDataContextConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
    => value is DataGridCell dataGridCell 
      && TryFindVisualParent(dataGridCell, out DataGrid dataGrid)
        ? dataGrid.DataContext
        : null;

  private bool TryFindVisualParent<TParent>(DependencyObject element, out TParent parent)
    where TParent : DependencyObject
  {
    while (element is not TParent and not null)
    {
      element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);
    }

    parent = element as TParent;
    return parent is not null;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
    => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to only show the ContextMenu on one of the columns? That was the reason why I had it as a child of the TemplateColumn

Comment: Yes it is possible. I have updated the example to show how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

When using an ItemsControl like `DataGrid`, the data context within its xaml (I mean, every xaml code that is enclosed between `<DataGrid>` and `</DataGrid>` ) refers to the type of its `ItemsSource`. That is in your case the class `Customer` and thus the error message "ICommand TimePointOnCommand property not found on object of type Customer." makes absolutely sense ;)

In short words: your binding is wrong.

One solution would be to give your ViewA a concrete name (for example "viewA") and change the binding to something like this:

```
<TextBlock.ContextMenu>
   <ContextMenu>
      <MenuItem
         Header="An Zeitpunkt festlegen"
         Command="{ Binding Path=DataContext.TimePointOnCommand, ElementName="viewA"}" />
   </ContextMenu>
</TextBlock.ContextMenu>
```